# What all things can be achieved using Installshield

Tags: deployment, installation, package, installshield

We have a requirement of automating the installation process for one of the client. At present we are doing the installation(which includes installing SQLServer Database, Installing and configuring IIS, Installing SSRS reports etc…) manually. I heard about Installshield, we are trying to achieve the following things, could you please let us know below mentioned things can be achieved thorough Installshield. Please provide your answers against the bulleted items inline.

1. Check for PreRequisites
2. Install PreRequisites
3. Accept values through Textboxes and use it in different screens
4. Display values and configurations in Grid
5. Connect to SQLServer
6. Check whether particular SQLServer Database exists or not
7. Create Database on SQLServer, location of the data and log file should be selected by the user depending on disk space.
8. Should be able to locate and run aspnet_regsql.exe
9. Restore SQLServer Database, some of the restoration values should be preselected(through setup we should be able to control/pass values to the DB restoration screen)
10. Whether C# programming is allowed?
11. What all the other scripting/programming languages it will support, if we need to do conditional installation and customization
12. Check for whether IIS installed, if not install it.
13. Check and create Application pools in IIS.
14. Using scripting/C# I should be able to control the configurations of IIS(Microsoft should have provided the API, but I should be able to use it in the Installshield setup)
15. Configure MIME in IIS, Enable and configure Windows Authentication in IIS.
16. XML support.
17. Add Connection strings to IIS
18. SMTP configuration
19. Add Roles to the Database
20. Install SSRS reports
21. Which product of Installshield will do the above things(eg: Installshield, Installshield Anywhere, Installshield Automation etc..)
22. If the above things can’t be achieved through Installshield, could you please suggest any other Installation/setup/package and deployment software do the same

With Regards,
Swaroop. M

Comment: Setup Development *is* Development. :)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, InstallShield can do all of these things. In practice, it's a very, very steep learning curve and a highly involved installer that you are looking at creating. I would probably bid this as a 1000 hour project and that's based on "been there done that"  with no learning curve.

I would consider using InstallShield to create an .MSI that merely checks and installs prereqs / windows features and lays down the content.  Then right a configuration utility to be run post-install to do all the SQL / SSRS / IIS configuration.  You'll get it done faster since you can use programing languages and frameworks that you already know.

Download and install Team Foundation Server Express  and use that as your model for a good user experience.  It's demonstrating all the things you ask for.